# Enabling touchesBegan after Animation Finished

Tags: objective-c, animation, touchesbegan

Newbie Here:

I have a series of animations that occur on my title screen and only after they have finished do I want the touchesBegan method to be enabled for the user to progress to the next view.  Is there any way to enable and disable the touchesBegan function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a BOOL and check its value in the touchesBegan method. Init it with NO value, and in the completion block of your animations, set its value to YES